# Need guidance on setting up people search

Tags: crawling, search-scope

I need some guidance on how to setup people search.

Would this http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=676af157-7d96-4e15-a987-54b8a3e4d948&ID=53 be a good link to follow in order to setup people search.

http://myserver/SearchCenter/peopleresults.aspx?k=mike&s=People

Comment: SharePoint configures a rule for Searching people out of the box. Are you having issues with it, trying to perform a custom search, or something else?

Comment: we provisioned a brand new test box and i need to setup people search as well as regular search like production. when i do create new site i dont see enterprise search as an optin. so i went to site settings and page layouts and site templates. i do see that the enterprise search is listed. hmm. i activated all the features as well. what's next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review this post.  It's a pretty good step by step on configuring Search.

http://sharepointgeorge.com/2010/configuring-enterprise-search-sharepoint-2010/